# Slow for loop speed in python using pandas, how to improve the strucutre?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop

I amwriting a code that runs at a nice speed if it wasn't for the preparation of my data...
The structure of my data is very particular and the only way I have currently found is to iterate with two for loops. This works fine for ~72000 indexes in my data frame but if I exceed this number, things start to slow down, bad...

This is the snippet of the code:

```html
for j in range(0,len(RWS_a[0][:])):
    for n in range(0,locN):
        
        DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'rws'] = RWS_a[n][j]
        DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'azim'] = WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j])*2
        DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'elev'] = -TILT[j]
        DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'range'] = dist[n]
        DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'x'] = dist[n]*np.cos(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j]))))
        DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'y'] = dist[n]*np.sin(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j]))))
        DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'z'] = 80+dist[n]*np.sin(np.radians(-TILT[j]))
    
    i = i+locN
```

Thanks in advance for your advice!

**UPDATE 30-07-2021**

I have found that using NumPy operations (np.tile, np.repeat and more) is incredibly much faster. I have made my routine more than 100x faster using NumPy instead of looping through indexes. I highly advise people struggling with for loops and time to five that a thought.

```html
DFt = pd.DataFrame()
DFt['time'] = ts
DFt['rws'] = np.ndarray.flatten(RWS_a, 'F')
DFt['azim'] = np.repeat(WT_DIR+angle*(0.5-LOS)*2,m)
DFt['elev'] = np.repeat(-TILT,m)
DFt['range'] = np.tile(dist,n)
DFt['x'] = np.tile(dist,n)*np.repeat(np.cos(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR+angle*(0.5-LOS))))*np.cos(np.radians(-TILT)),m)
DFt['y'] = np.tile(dist,n)*np.repeat(np.sin(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR+angle*(0.5-LOS))))*np.cos(np.radians(-TILT)),m)
DFt['z'] = z_LiDAR+np.tile(np.array(dist),n)*np.repeat(np.sin(np.radians(-TILT)),m)
```

Comment: Why are you copying a list just to take its length?  Just use `len(RWS_a[0])`.  It won't change the list, and it will produce the same result at taking the length of a copy.  The original code seems to be using a bad idiom.

Comment: More relevant:  All of your trig calls seem to be invariant in the inner loop, so why keep making the same calls over and over again?  Move them *out of the loop*.

Comment: Good point, but I have already tried to test the speed of the loop with the right calls inside and outside of the loop. I did not see a sensible difference in speed really (maybe 1-5%). This makes me think that the main problem is somewhere else.

Comment: ```i = i+locN``` Is the ```i``` used in a loop or what ?

Answer (score 0):

A completely runable code would be fine, so we could test. All the RHS (right hand sides) of the equations are vectorizable and much faster in numpy without for loops. It's not obvious wether you really need this rather complicated index construction of the left hand side (pandas).

```
# this suggestion works for the right hand side only !
# try to simplify the left hand side

j = slice(RWS_a[0][:]))
n = slice(0,locN)
        
DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'rws']   = RWS_a[n,j]
DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'azim']  = WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j])*2
DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'elev']  = -TILT[j]
DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'range'] = dist[n]
DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'x']     = dist[n]*np.cos(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j]))))
DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'y']     = dist[n]*np.sin(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j]))))
DF.loc[DF.index[i+n], 'z']     = 80+dist[n]*np.sin(np.radians(-TILT[j]))
```

You might do first

```
j = slice(RWS_a[0][:]))
n = slice(0,locN)
        
A = RWS_a[n,j]
B = WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j])*2
C = -TILT[j]
D = dist[n]
E = dist[n]*np.cos(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j]))))
F = dist[n]*np.sin(np.radians(90-(WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j]))))
G = 80+dist[n]*np.sin(np.radians(-TILT[j]))
```

and then store it into pandsas with something like

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": A,
     "B": B,
     "C": C,
     "D": D,
     "E": E,
     "F": F,
     "G": G } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Code optimisations that I could think of:

- You are calculating `i+n` multiple times in your inner loop. Store that in a variable and use it wherever required.

  > `idx = i+n`
- The RHS values that use `j` only can be moved out of inner loop. You are unnecessarily re-calculating them. Calculate these once, store them in variables and use them wherever required.

  > `azim = WT_DIR[j]+angle*(0.5-LOS[j])*2`

  > `elev = -TILT[j]`

  > All the Trigonometry functions